# Centering View that is larger than its container at Android

Tags: android, centering

We have a horizontal `LinearLayout` that contains a bunch of vertical `LinearLayout`, programmatically created. The **total sum** of vertical `LinearLayout` **width** is bigger than its container, so I would like to show just the center elements (without scrolling and without removal, just positioning somehow).

Is there anyway to center the horizontal `LinearLayout` in its `RelativeLayout` **container**?

Horizontal `LinearLayout` is **larger** than its container, that is a **root element**, RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" />
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You could try with android:gravity="center_horizontal" in the RelativeLayout

Comment: What if you set the RelativeLayout's width to be larger than the screen?

Comment: This way, how can I center the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to accomplish that just using RelativeLayout and LinearLayout. Those doesn't offer "scroll". You must wrap the content of LinearLayout and wrap it on a HorizontalScrollView and do "the math" to scroll to the center or use a ViewPager, Gallery or another view container that offers scroll for contained views.

Comment: I didn't get it. Could you give onde example? What is do the math? @fr4gus

Comment: You need to measure the child views and calculate the center of them and use HorizontalScrollView.scrollTo(int x, int y) to move the scroll view to it's center.

Comment: Interesting. I will try it now. @fr4gus

Comment: I need to (manual) get child view size or there's any place inside HorizontalScrollView that I can get this value?

Comment: I got it this way: `(HorizontalScrollView.getChildAt(0).getWidth() - screenWidth) / 2`. Thank you.